Duplicate Hair Curve Node Not Masking Properly in Geometry Nodes
I've been working extensively with the Geo hair system, but I've hit a roadblock when it comes to making the Duplicate Hair Curve node play nicely with vertex group data. Here's the situation:
Issue
The Duplicate Hair Curve node doesn't seem to respond to vertex group masking as expected. Despite trying various node setups, I haven't achieved the desired results.
Custom Masking Attempts
I experimented with custom masking Geometry Nodes, which worked well with an interpolate hair curve. However, when it comes to the Duplicate Hair Curve node, things get tricky. I've already created six characters using this node, so starting from scratch isn't an ideal solution.
Seeking Solutions
Is there a way to fix this without discarding my existing duplicate hair curves?
